# How can I create a button per Typescript Code, that has an onclick function?

Tags: angular, typescript, function, events, onclick

i am programming with Angular.

My question is, how can I create a button or an other element in the Typescript Code, that has a (click) function?

I made it that way, but it didn't work, it only created the button / element but not the onclick event (If I pressed it, nothing happened).

```
createDivs() {
    const textausgabe = document.querySelector('#textausgabe');
    textausgabe.innerHTML = '<div [ngClass]="[bntStyle]" (click)="functionCaller()">Submit</div>';

  }

  functionCaller() {
    alert('Hey');
  }
```

So is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: Can you not just do this with with a child component? Or must the inner HTML be set in javascript?

Comment: just use *ngIf if you want to add or remove element in DOM

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, you don't. This is not the angular way to do things. If you need to add a button, just use a `*ngIf` directive.

```
@Component({template: '<div *ngIf="showSubmit" [ngClass]="[bntStyle]" (click)="functionCaller()">Submit</div>'})
class Somecomponent {

  showSubmit = false;

  createDivs() {
    this.showSubmit = true;
  }

  functionCaller() {
    alert('Hey');
  }
```

If you need to add a random number of buttons based on user input, you can use `*ngFor`for iterating over user input.

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to add a random amount of buttons, for example if that depends on a user input?

Comment: @Lukas1231241243 This isn't an incorrect answer - it answered the problem you posted. You are now changing the problem. And also, you need to learn what problem Angular is solving. It lets you build dynamic HTML based on your model. The component-based approach is a *perfect* solution to your revised problem

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like this.

Use this code in HTML file.

If you have some specific case to show or hide this. 
You need to use *ngIf for the condition.

To manipulate this condition you use ngModel and use that variable in *ngIf.

I hope this will help.